# Getting paste method failed error on code

Tags: vba, excel

I have some issues with this code whereby it gives error message on the `wS.Range("B1").Paste Link:=True`. This code allows the user to select a range and that range should paste on every sheet of the workbook, in the designated row range B1 to N1 .It says method of paste method failed. Trying including the whole range `("B1:N1")` but still getting the same error. Some help would be good. Thank you !

```
   Sub test()
      Dim Rng As Range, _
        Inp As Range, _
        wS As Worksheet

    Set Inp = Selection
    Inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TypeName(Rng) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Rng.Parent.Activate
        Inp.Copy

        For Each wS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            wS.Range("B1").Paste Link:=True
        Next
    End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell your requirement for this code. You just explain the code. I want to know the requirement before code.

Comment: I want the code to be able to copy a specific range from the database sheet and paste to all other sheets(range B1:N1) of the workbook .

Comment: `Range` object does not have `Paste` method. If you want to imrove your chances of getting help, start with creating [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
Sub test()
      Dim Rng As Range, _
        Inp As Range, _
        wS As Worksheet


    Set Inp = Selection
    Inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TypeName(Rng) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Inp.Copy

        For Each wS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            Inp.Copy wS.Range(Rng(1).Address)
        Next
    End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: what does the '(Rng(1).Address)' mean . It does not work. No effect after running!

Comment: and there is no paste ? It is supposed to paste to every other sheet in the active workbook, it is put as copy instead. Unless i got the idea of ur code wrongly